# React async loading of configuration variables

Tags: reactjs, react-native, auth0

I am very new to React, and I cannot seem to solve a simple problem. I am implementing the auth0 lock widget, and have imported it in my 'routes.js' as follows:

*routes.js*:

```
import {requireAuth} from './js/helpers/AuthService.js';
```

My AuthService.js does not have a constructor, it only contains declarations of functions, some of which must be exported. Snippet:

*AuthService.js*:

```
  const lock = new Auth0Lock(
  client_id,
  domain, {
    auth: {
      redirectUrl: `${window.location.origin}${LOGIN_ROUTE}`,
      responseType: 'token id_token',
        params: {
         scope: 'openid email' 
      },
    }
  }
);

const events = new EventEmitter();

lock.on('authenticated', authResult => {
  setAccessToken(authResult.accessToken);
  lock.getUserInfo(authResult.accessToken, (error, profile) => {
    if (error) { return setProfile({error}); }
    setProfile(profile);
    browserHistory.push(getNextPath());
    clearNextPath();
  });
});

export function login(options) {
  lock.show(options);

  return {
    hide() {
      lock.hide();
    }
  }
}
(etc.)
```

The only thing I want to achieve is to load the 'client_id' and 'domain' variables through an API call, before everything else loads. So basically something like:

```
# fetch the config variables
fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
       throw new Error("Bad response from server");
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
     const client_id = data.client_id
     const domain = data.domain
  });

  # Proceed with normal flow
  const lock = new Auth0Lock(
  client_id,
  domain, {
    auth: {
      redirectUrl: `${window.location.origin}${LOGIN_ROUTE}`,
      responseType: 'token id_token',
        params: {
         scope: 'openid email' 
      },
    }
  }
);
```

The problem I have is that the fetch is an async call, so the other code does not wait for it to finish, which triggers errors in the rest of the code (client_id and domain are undefined).

I have read about the componentDidMount function, but it is always mentioned that this can be used to delay rendering. I have nothing to render, I just want to declare some functions. For this, I only need some constant variables to be set based on an API call. This can't be that had, but I cannot seem to find a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am very new to React, so maybe you can wait a confirmation from someone else.

You are getting information via fetch and assigning them to some variables but your normal flow does not know those variables (or new values) at that time as you explained. So, you can use states here. As a new React developer, I start with some default states, in componentDidMount I do my Ajax stuff and change state there (setState). So, your component will be rerendered again since state is changed.

Comment: That would mean I have to put my functions in a class which extends from Component, right? But then how can I still export these functions?

Comment: I don't know your design but you can easily export a component (even a pure function) with standard export methods (module.exports or export with ES6). Your main component holds the states, those states will handle your variables or whatever you want, you will do Ajax stuff in a suitable place like componentDidMount. But as I said I don't know your design, what will trigger states? If you don't render anything (and you don't have any React code in your example) maybe you should focus on JS itself. Promises or even async functions in ES7 (soo new). As I said, I'm a newbie :)

Answer (score 0):

You can invok your async worker before loading your app with the help of [react-async-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-async-wrapper)

```
import React from 'react';
import { AsyncComponent } from 'react-async-wrapper';

export default class AsyncApp extend React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <AsyncComponent asyncProps={{
                lock: () => fetch(url)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            if (response.status >= 400) {
                                throw new Error("Bad response from server");
                            }
                            return response.json();
                        })
                        .then(data => ({
                            new Auth0Lock(
                                data.client_id,
                                data.domain,
                                {
                                    auth: {
                                        redirectUrl: `${window.location.origin}${LOGIN_ROUTE}`,
                                        responseType: 'token id_token',
                                        params: {
                                            scope: 'openid email' 
                                        },
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                        });
            }}>
                <App/> //now in App, you can accept lock by this.props.lock
            </AsyncComponent>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical asynchronous case, if you feel that all your components depend on the output of the `fetch()` function call, you have to list it all under `.then()`, something like `fetch(url).then( all of your code here)`.

Having said that, if you need to render some components based on what has been returned from fetch, you can use `setState({})` in `.then()` and call those components in the `render()` method accordingly.